# Proper metric to compare continuous to discrete data?

Tags: biostatistics, r-squared, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have two measurements of the same thing. The first is a subjective rating score, the second is a quantitative metric. The rating score is discrete (0-10), while the quantitative metric is any value between 0 and 10. What is the proper metric to assess the agreement between these two different methods? I have seen people simply round the continuous value to the closest integer and compute Cohen's kappa, but that seems wrong since you're throwing away information. Of course one could compute R^2, but that has its own issues. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: See the similar https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88189/calculating-agreement-between-an-ordinal-and-continuous-scale

Comment: What’s wrong with $R^2?$